# How to get the first address of a running application in Android

Tags: android, process

I have this code:

```
    ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) this.getSystemService( ACTIVITY_SERVICE );
    List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> procInfos = activityManager.getRunningAppProcesses();
    for(ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo runningProInfo:procInfos){

        Log.d("Running Processes", "()()" + runningProInfo.processName);

        //print the first address of a process here
        //For example: 0x00001234
    }
```

I can get all the running process in my devices, however I don't know how to get the first address of them.

Can we get it in Android?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can get it by below code

```
 ActivityManager activityManager = (ActivityManager) this.getSystemService( ACTIVITY_SERVICE );
    List<ActivityManager.RunningAppProcessInfo> procInfos = activityManager.getRunningAppProcesses();

        Log.d("Running Processes", "()() first process" + procInfos.get(0).processName);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but that's not what I want, I just want to print the first address of each process here.

For example, my process is located at 0x0001234, I want to print that location.

Comment: can you explain more what you exactly want? it currently shows app package.

Comment: If I use your code, I'll get the app name.

If my process takes 20 MB ram and locate at 0x00001234 address, do we have any function to get the value of that address? For example:

var address = getAdress(appID);

Comment: The reason why I want to do it because with that address, I can read another address of any application with an offset value.

Comment: I want the number of the address where my program starts

Comment: you can get memory info. I don't think u can get this address.

Comment: Yes, I can get info of memory, thank you. I think I have no solution for this case.